# What set of numbers can be used to describe a polyhedron?

Tags: geometry

How can any polyhedra be described? For instance, are the same things that make a tetrahedron different from a cube the same things that make a cube different from an octahedron? Since a triangular prism is a tetrahedron glued to a square based pyramid, a triangular prism's *'stuff'* is likely the sum of a tetrahedron's and a square based pyramid's *'stuff'*. So what set of numbers can be used to describe a polyhedron? This is only for regular polyhedra, for example, all parallelepipeds are considered cubes.

Comment: Are you asking for a general definition of a polyhedron?

Comment: Well, yes. I think. If I give you some numbers that are derived from some polyhedron, could you find that polyhedron with just the numbers?

Comment: I mean, you first probably need to assume the faces are all regular. Otherwise, this is quite obviously impossible.

Comment: How are you associating a polyhedron to numbers?

Comment: That is the question I'm asking. How would you turn a polyhedron into numbers, so that it could be reconstructed with just the numbers?

Comment: You can store the coordinates of the vertices of the polyhedron (the so-called $\mathcal{V}$-description), in which case the polyhedron can be recovered as the convex hull. Another way would be to store the linear inequalities defining the faces of the polyhedron (the so-called $\mathcal{H}$-description). Is this what you mean?

Comment: It might help if you can specify what you would consider to be a set of numbers that adequately describe a *polygon*; once you can do that, it should be straightforward to determine whether a corresponding description, as numbers, can be given for polyhedra.

Comment: What the OP is asking seems quite clear to me. He wants to store some set of numbers that completely describe a given polyhedron (in a computer system, presumably), and he's asking what those numbers should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking (I think) is how one would numerically represent a polyhedron, perhaps in a computer system.

There is an entire field called "[solid modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_modeling)" that deals with computer (i.e. numerical) representations of 3D solid objects. The most widely used scheme is a "boundary representation". As the name implies, this means that the solid object is represented by storing some information about its boundary (i.e. its bounding surfaces). Generally, solid objects can have curved surfaces; a polyhedron is just the special case where all the surfaces happen to be planar.

One possible representation would be:

1. Store a list of the $(x,y,z)$ coordinates of the vertices.
2. For each edge of the polyhedron, store references to its two vertices
3. For each face of the polyhedron, store references to its bounding edges

There are many other ways to organize the data. A popular one is the [winged edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winged_edge) data structure.

The above is all about completely general polyhedra. Significant simplifications are possible for special cases, such as

1. Convex polyhedra
2. Polyhedra whose faces are all triangles
3. Regular polyhedra (all faces having identical size and shape)